# Add same product multiple times in cart

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I would like to have products in the the cart to be separate from one another. The table with the cart lines in PrestaShop is `ps_cart_product` and has a primary key on `id_cart`, `id_product` and `id_attribute`, so I should do something with "customizations" in PrestaShop. I know there is `$cart->_addCustomization()`, but I don't understand the function after attempting to customize a product in the cart like so with a module:

```
public function hookActionCartSave($params)
{
    $cart = $this->context->cart;
    $last_cart_product = $cart->getLastProduct();

    $cart->_addCustomization(
        $last_cart_product['id_product'],
        $last_cart_product['id_product_attribute'],
        $index = 1,
        $type = 2,
        md5(time().$last_cart_product['id_product'].$last_cart_product['id_product_attribute']),
        10
    );
}
```

As you might see I hardcoded some variables just to check it out.

## Purpose

I would like the customer to be able to customize the product later (upload a file). Let's say we have a *Product 1* and a customer wants 50 with a certain print on it, and another 50 with an other print on it. The customization process will be done after the order is placed (different problem, not my question here).

**Is this the way to do what I want, and if so how?**

Edit:
So far I managed to add a customization in the database. However, does not seem to be complete. When I printout the `$products` in `shopping-cart.tpl`, I see `["customization_quantity"] => NULL`, so it might not be added to the cart properly.

Comment: As you pointed out, the primary key is id_cart, id_product, id_product_attribute, id_address_delivery. So it won't be possible to have 2 entries of the same product with the same constraints. you either change this restrition (risking crashing something else) or find a workaround (maybe a module to input multiple costumizations for a product based on qty)

Comment: The function in my question is from my module. I tried to add 10 (as you can see in the code example), but this doesn't just put `quantity=10` in `ps_customization` in the database. I see a records in `ps_customization` with `ps_customized_data`, but in my cart it still appears as one product. I would like to have the products in my cart as if the were different product attributes.

Comment: Does it really needs to be separated in database? Or do you only want to show on separate lines in the shopping cart? For the second case, you'll be able to do this in tpl files.

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre Well not really. The purpose is to have a distinction between products. It want the customer to be able to customize the product at a later moment (upload a file). So it is indeed more about how it looks at the front-end. How would I go about to edit the `shopping-cart.tpl`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
public function hookActionCartSave($params)
{
    $last_cart_product = $this->context->cart->getLastProduct();
    $product = new Product($last_cart_product['id_product']);
    if ($product) {
        if (!$field_ids = $product->getCustomizationFieldIds()) {
            return;
        }

        $authorized_text_fields = array();
        foreach ($field_ids as $field_id) {
            if ($field_id['type'] == Product::CUSTOMIZE_TEXTFIELD) {
                $authorized_text_fields[(int)$field_id['id_customization_field']] = 'textField'.(int)$field_id['id_customization_field'];
            }
        }

        $print_reference = $this->uniqueCustomizationReference();

        $indexes = array_flip($authorized_text_fields);
        foreach ($authorized_text_fields as $field_name => $value) {
            $this->context->cart->addTextFieldToProduct($product->id, $field_name, Product::CUSTOMIZE_TEXTFIELD, $print_reference);
        }
    }
}
```

What this does is for every product, that has the option of being customised, it adds a "customization" for that cart line into the database. In this case only `addTextFieldToProduct()` is added at the end, because I wanted every cart line to be a separate entity, called 'print product'.

In the PrestaShop backoffice you should make customizations possible under `Products >> Product {x} >> Customizations >> Text = 1 | label = 'print product'`